# Docker error running image hyperkube-amd64:v1.7.0

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

While trying to run the next Docker command:

```
docker run \
--net=host \
--pid=host \
--privileged=true \
-d \
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.7.0 \
/nsenter \
  --target=1 \
  --mount \
  --wd=. \
  -- ./hyperkube kubelet \
    --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
    --address="0.0.0.0" \
    --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
    --config=etc/kubernetes/manifests \
    --v=2
```

I am getting an error

> nsenter: failed to execute ./hyperkube: No such file or directory

I have been trying a lot of combination, but nothing seems to work, have someone else tried to do this before?

My docker version is

```
Client:
  Version:      1.12.6
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.6.4
  Git commit:   78d1802
  Built:        Wed Jan 11 00:23:16 2017
  OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
  Version:      1.12.6
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.6.4
  Git commit:   78d1802
  Built:        Wed Jan 11 00:23:16 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried your command and the error i got is `Error: unknown flag: --config` I removed that and the container is now running

Answer (score 1):

kubernetes [doesn't support Docker 17.06](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/1542#issuecomment-315201536). Try Docker 1.12.6 instead.

Comment: I already tried with Docker 1.12.6, but still having the same issue nsenter: failed to execute ./hyperkube: No such file or directory, thanks

Comment: Have you tried @tarun-lalwani's suggestion? `--config=etc/kubernetes/manifests` is incorrect and should be replaced with `--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

Hyperkube is not designed to run in macOS so i had to use other kind of kubernetes server for local development and that work perfectly:

I am currently using [kubeadm-dind-cluster](https://github.com/Mirantis/kubeadm-dind-cluster)